# Numbers plotted by ListPlot don't match the data

Tags: plotting, special-functions, precision-and-accuracy

My mathematica is doing weird things. Consider the function

```
f[n_]:=Re[(1/2)*(I*Pi+(-1)^n*n!*Gamma[-n,-n])]
```

Let's make a list out of this

```
points:=Table[{n,f[n]},{n,60,63}]
```

when evaluated I get that the list points has these four entries

```
N@points

(* {{60., 0.0539289}, {61., 0.0534851}, {62., 0.00402142}, {63.,0.00395776}} *)
```

That is, the first two are above 0.05 and  the last two are significantly smaller. Nonetheless, when I perform a ListPlot of points I get a plot where the four dots are way above 0.05. What is going on? Is this a bug?

```
ListPlot[points, PlotRange -> {0, 0.06}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Comment: Your `Table` is missing an iterator (`n`) and `Gamma[-60,-60]` doesn't evaluate for me.  Did you transcribe your code correctly?

Comment: edited and Gamma[-60,-60] evaluates without any problems to me

Comment: In order to see the decimal output you show, you had to use `N`, otherwise you would see something with very large integers multiplied by `Gama[-60,-60]`, so I added that line to the post.  So if you use `ListPlot[N@points]` then you see what you expect

Comment: @JasonB. ok. But why does not my code work? It should work shouldnt it?

Comment: @AnarchistBirdsWorshipFungus - you are multiplying very huge numbers (10^83) by very small numbers (10^-82), so you have to give some consideration to precision.  I think that `ListPlot` is being smarter than `N` in this case, check the output from this:  `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 100},
 N[points, {∞, 5}]
 ] `

Comment: right the plot is correct. default `N` is getting it wrong.  Just do `N[points, 20]` to see the correct values.   Just by the way (unrelated to the issue) but you should not be using set delayed `points:=` here. That says to recompute the table every time you use the symbol `points`

Comment: @JasonB. thanks.  what does the {Infinity,5} stand for in side N in your code?

Comment: @AnarchistBirdsWorshipFungus I was just looking at the docs page for `N`.    From m_goldberg's answer you see extra argument wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`N @ points` is using machine arithmetic and giving you bad values at 62 and 63. Changing over to Mathematica's arbitrary precision arithmetic, even at the fairly low precision of 20 digits,

```
N[points, 20]
```

gives

```
{{60.000000000000000000, 0.053928873945168632029}, 
 {61.000000000000000000, 0.053485094513170474678}, 
 {62.000000000000000000, 0.053052093270633190146}, 
 {63.000000000000000000, 0.052629440880266559186}}
```

showing that your list plot is correct.